# Trouble with the Yodlee login call

Tags: yodlee

I'm working through the steps in the Aggregation REST Quick Start Guide (https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_REST_Quick_Start_Guide).

I'm able to successfully request a CoBrand Session Token using our private zone URL:
consolidatedsdk.yodlee.com/yodsoap/srest/private-XXX/v1.0/authenticate/coblogin

I'm also able to successfully register new users with:
consolidatedsdk.yodlee.com/yodsoap/srest/private-XXX/v1.0/jsonsdk/UserRegistration/register3

However, I'm not able to login users.  I get a 404 error for the following URL:
consolidatedsdk.yodlee.com/yodsoap/srest/private-XXX/v1.0/authenticate/login

(Obviously I've obfuscated our actual Private Zone URL for security purposes)

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

Try not to copy-paste Rest URL and endpoint from site, but type it by yourself.
I had the same error (415 system_error), but after typing it manually everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

It should be because of any of the below two reasons -

1. You are accessing the API from an IP which is not whitelisted with Yodlee.
2. The URL may contain spaces which is why the URL is not recognized by Yodlee.

Please make sure both of the above point is considered while making a request as login API is working properly in the environment which your Private zone is configured.

Comment: Neither of these is the case.  I am clearly accessing the API from an authorized URL as the other calls are succeeding.  And there are no spaces in the URL.

After making NO changes on my end, now instead of a 404, I am seeing:
    <Error>
        <errorCode>415</errorCode>
        <errorDetail>system_error</errorDetail>
    </Error>

Comment: can you raise a service request using Yodlee customer care which is provided along with private zone credentials. Please provide the complete URL and other details in the service request. We will have to check internally on this.

Comment: I'd love to but the YCC username and password I was provided is not working.  I sent an email off to the support address.